# What is the point of an Initialization Vector in AES CBC?

Tags: cryptography

I'm planning to use symmetrical encryption to transfer a file from computer A to B. The password is entered into both computers manually and never to be transmitted online. From what I understand, IV is not confidential and is to be transmitted alongside the encrypted data and should be randomized each time for a new chunk. My question is.. why? Can't I just give it a block's worth of 0's each time? It has to have some reason for existing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IV is used in encrypting the first block you transmit. You XOR the first block of plaintext with the IV, then encrypt the result.

A unique IV for each message ensures that the first block changes from one message to the next, even if both the content and the encryption key were identical. Without that, messages might well be subject to traffic analysis, even if the attacker couldn't read the actual content. A typical example would be a message format in which every message starts with basically the same header, but with a "To:" field telling who the message goes to, or a "Re:" part telling about the subject.

In such a case, analysis over time could reveal patterns that relate the first block to types of traffic, events that (apparently) triggered the message, and so on. Based upon this, an attacker could (for example) have at least some idea when events of different types had been detected, even without being able to decrypt/read any of the plaintext directly.

Summary: A unique IV for each message ensures that the encrypted version of each block is different between messages, even when/if the content and key are identical.

Comment: In addition: CBC makes sure that one block of ciphertext differs from another, even if it has the same content, by XOR'ing the previous block of ciphertext (the vector) with the plain text. Obviously that doesn't work for the first block, so you need an IV (initialization vector) *if* the key is reused to encrypt another message.

Comment: Minor note: if the IV is static then more than one block may be equal to a prevously encrypted block, until a block is encountered that hadn't been encountered before.

Comment: @owlstead: Yes--a static IV (i.e., one that doesn't change from one message to the next) is basically pointless. I think of an IV as being similar to a salt on a hashed password--in each case, it basically forces an attacker to look at each (message|password) in isolation, instead of being able to treat them as a group.

Comment: Oh, that's clever. I checked encrypted bytes generated by the AES built into .net and it appears that the IV gets applied automatically when encrypting/decrypting so I don't have to manually XOR it with the first block, right?

Comment: @user81993: I haven't used .NET for that, but it certainly seems reasonable that given a mode of operation and an IV, it would use the IV appropriately for that mode of operation.